# GWT : separate js + css + images from server

Tags: gwt, same-origin-policy

We'd like to have the following configuration :

- one server is replying to GWT RPC : x.com (the one running Java)
- another server is serving js / css / images : y.com (for bandwith optimization)

So the main page is :  http://x.com/index.html 
and contains this line:  `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://**x.com**/my-app.nocache.js"></script>`

We're getting a SOP error: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL ...

Any suggestion, help about that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following to your gwt.xml:

```
<add-linker name="xsiframe" />
```

This will generate slightly different code, that can be loaded cross-origin. Your "host page" will still have to be loaded from the same server you run your GWT-RPC servlets on, to not hit the SOP.

See [this FAQ entry](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_Server.html#What_is_the_Same_Origin_Policy,_and_how_does_it_affect_GWT?) (the "xs" linker predates the "xsiframe" one, that latter is now preferred, and could eventually even replace the "std", default linker)

Answer (score 1):

You have hit [Same Origin Policy](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/trunk/FAQ_Server.html#What_is_the_Same_Origin_Policy,_and_how_does_it_affect_GWT?) which prevents making XMLHTTPRequest to servers other than origin server. This effectively prevents cross-domain GWT-RPC.

The possible workarounds are described in [Making cross-site requests](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/Xsite.html):

1. Run a proxy on your server
2. Load the JSON response into a `<script>` tag

Comment: Thx - this is not about making several GWT RPC to different origins but separating the actual WEB resources (images, css, js, html) from the only GWT RPC server. Dunno if it's possible?

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm talking about: SOP says that you can only communicate back to the domain (server) from which your HTML+JS was loaded.

Comment: So, are you loading .js files from x server or grom y server?

Comment: Also, do you have javascript that comes from different domains (x,y) that tries to access each other?

Comment: No only the GWT "resources" on one server for bandwidth purpose and the "RPC" server on the other one.

Comment: Yep, that's SOP limitation: JS comes from one server and tries to talk to another server. Browsers do not allow this. Second link discusses possible workarounds.